# How does JSF tags affect JSP lifecycle methods? What about JSP and facelets?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

Do JSP lifecycle methods run when using JSF tags in JSP pages? If so, what is the sequence?

Do JSP lifecycle methods run when using facelets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a very clarifying article on the subject [in IBM's DeveloperWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-facelets/). On the subjetc of using JSP's in JSF applications it says the following:

> The body of the JSP becomes the equivalent of a servlet's doGet() and
>   doPost() methods (that is, it becomes the jspService() method). The
>   JSF custom tags (such as f:view and h:form) are just calls to the JSF
>   components to render themselves in their current state. The life cycle
>   of the JSF component model is independent from the life cycle of the
>   JSP-produced servlet.

So, the answer to your first question is yes; JSP pages follow their own lifecycle and JSF Components follow their own. On Facelets, you can also find this:

> Unlike JSP, Facelets is a templating language built from the ground up
>   with the JSF component life cycle in mind. With Facelets, you produce
>   templates that build a component tree, not a servlet.

With that, there's no need of using JSP's with JSF if you're already using Facelets. So the answer to your second question would be no, as there are no JSP pages at all.

Comment: when we use JSF on a JSP page, how does their lifecycles interweave?

Comment: As stated, JSP simply renders the current state of JSF Components and JSP's have a very simple lifecycle (compile into Page Class, Page Class handles request). If you were using Servlets with JSF, you just instantiate JSF UI Components and show their state: The complexity in lifecycles comes from JSF, not from JSP/Servlets.

Answer (score 2):

The JSP lifecycle methods (whatever those are) do not run when using JSF with Facelets, for the simple reason that Facelets is 100% separate from JSP.

You should btw never use JSF with JSP. It's a deprecated VDL for JSF, doesn't support the latest JSF features, and is just wrong.

Comment: "is just wrong" is to answer questions from people who seek help. Could you elaborate on why it's wrong to use JSP with JSF and what features are missing (or point to an answer in SO or an article)? For the moment, -1.